# Unitary invariant positive definite form

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

> Let $G$ be a finite group and $V$ a finite-dimensional compex vector space which is a $G$-module. Define $(u,v)=\sum_{x\in G} h(ux,vx)$, where $h(u,v)$ is a positive-definite hermitian form. By choosing an orthonormal basis of $V$ relative to the form $(u,v)$ show that any representation of $G$ is equivalent to a unitary representation, and deduce that $V$ is semisimple.

What's a unitary representation? I get that a unitary matrix is a matrix whose Hermitian conjugate is equal to its inverse, and that a unitary group of order $n$ is the set of $n\times n$ unitary matrices. Is it a group homomorphism from a group to a group of unitary matrices?

Second, the solution says that $(u,v)$ is a unitary invariant positive definite form. Does that mean that it's invariant under the action of $G$ (i.e. $(ux,vx)=(u,v) \forall x\in G$), and that $(u,v)$ is a unitary operator (i.e. $(Au,v)(u,A^*v)=I$)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't claim to be an expert in this area, but my reading mostly agrees with yours.

I think you are correct that a unitary representation is a representation in which every element of $g$ is represented as a unitary matrix.

And also that a unitary invariant positive definite form means that

1. the form is unitary: you can use the elements of $G$ as a basis for $V$, and write the Gram matrix $B$ for $(u,v)$ (so that $(u,v) = u^{T} B v$); then $B$ should be unitary.
2. invariant: I would read this as invariant under $G$, like you did.
3. positive definite, so $(u,u) \geq 0$, $(u,u) =0 \iff u=0$